# iTunes on iOS shows song genre instead of a title for random albums (the same album on Mac shows everything correctly)

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music

I have a mp3 album on my old drive. I've imported it to iTunes on my Mac. Everything looks correctly.

[image]

When I want to sync that album to my iPhone, it's synced however instead of track titles I see that kind of weird stuff:

[image]
[image]

It drives me nuts and I can't have it like that.

What's funny, when I go on my iPhone to:

`Settings -> Music -> Downloaded Music -> Depeche Mode -> 101`

I see all titles displayed correctly the way I would expect in iTunes.

[image]

What's going on? Please advise.

Comment: Nobody experience the same issue? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually had the same issue for a specific album. I fixed it by going to the Album's info, checking the box titled "Use Work and Movement" and deleting the text in the "Work" field, and syncing the phone.

[image: Checking "Use work and Movement", and leaving "work" blank fixed the issue]

Comment: As an addition, after ticking the box and removing the content of the work input, you can safely untick the box again and then sync.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If (like me) you have a large number of albums affected, you can select them all and choose "Get Info". However, since it shows a greyed out "mixed" you must first enter something into work and apply it (I just used "test"). Then after that is done, you can go back in and delete test, and apply that change.

For me this issue applied to almost all of my imported albums. iTunes seems to be applying the style field (not actually genre) from flac/mp3 albums I import to the work field for some reason.